# iOS photo viewing app that allows me to manually organize the order of images

Tags: ios, photography, image-viewer

The default photos app in iOS is organized by date of capture. The ability exists to create custom albums, but the images are sorted by the time that you added the image to the album. I am looking for an app that allows me to add images to an album, and rearrange them as desired regardless of when the image was captured or when I added the image to the album.

Ultimately what I am trying to accomplish is before/after shots of DIY projects that may include images captured over a long duration. Then I can flip between before/after images easily.

I am using iOS 8.4 on an iPhone 6+.

Comment: Are you jailbroken? iirc this was pretty much made impossible when the default location for photos became "camera roll" rather than photos

Comment: No jailbrake. Note I don't want to move photos around in the Photos app itself or physically where they are stored. I want to just rearrange them for playback purposes.

Comment: Another possibility, could be to install a photo collage album app. Create the initial album with one page for each step, and let each page have space for two images (before and after), and fill in the before pictures. After completing the project, reedit the collage album and fill in the after pictures.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to draw your attention to [Minimal Folio](//www.simonheys.com/minimalfolio/), which have some interesting features I've not seen in others photo/album organizer which easily can be adapted to your DIY projects features.

Some of the features which you can take advantage over:

- It can of course import images either from cameral roll or via iTunes
- It can sync albums to Dropbox
- It can create multiple albums, i.e. one for each DIY projects
- Albums consists of images grouped by columns, and you can easily rearrange images in these columns
- You drag sideways to switch columns, and drag up and down to choose within a column
- When switching columns it remembers where you are at in that column

One way to use this column feature, could be to have one column for each view/room/stage/..., and then have the before and after images within that column. At the top of the column you could have the before images, and then as you progress you add after images to the column.

This allows for you to swipe sideways through the different views, and then swipe up or down to flip before before and after images. Minimal Folio isn't gratis, but it is currently priced at 2.99 USD, which for me was well spent money.

Comment: Appears to be iPad only. I am on an iPhone.

Comment: Ah... Saw the ios tag, and forgot about your last specification of iPhone. That was a bit sad, because I do believe it would have helped you.

Comment: Yeah no problem. I didn't want to make the title any longer so I popped it into the full question. It may help future users so please do leave the answer here!

Comment: Searching also indicates that it _has_ been available for the iPhone, but that is sadly to no help for you.

Answer (score 0):

Since Minimal Folio isn't available for iPhone, I would like to give you an alternative approach on how to get your wanted functionality.

If you use a photo album/organizer which has tags, you could opt for tagging your projects, and then view smart albums based on the tags. One scheme for such tags could be:

- A `before` and `after` tag
- A unique project tag, `my DIY no 1`
- (Optional) A dedicated tag within the project, to identify the stage/view/room/step, i.e. `step1`, `step2`, ...

Now you if the app allows it, you can make a smart album filtered on the unique project tag, and then sorted on the step (or similar tag), and view the before and after picture.

Some untested alternatives which at least has both iPad and iPhone apps, and seems to support tags are: Smart Photo Album, PixSort and Swipix. All found after searching for `photo album tags` in the App Store, and reading some of the reviews.

Happy hunting for a good photo organizer app.